# SubClassing a sub-class in swift (skspritenode)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, subclass, skspritenode

I'm currently making a game that will have multiple types of enemies, I currently made the basic enemy using a subclass of SKSpriteNode and everything is working fine.  I now want to implement another sub class of the basic enemy since all the enemies are similar.  I am having trouble creating the new subclass. Any help would be much appreciated.  Here is my code...

```
class Basic_Fighter : SKSpriteNode  {

    var health : Int = 3
    var ship_speed : Double = 7.0
    var bullet_rapidness : Double = Double ((arc4random_uniform(3) + 2) )
    var bullet_speed : Double = 3.0
    var action = SKAction()
    var bullet_Timer : NSTimer?


    func subtract_health(){ health-- }

    func enemy_killed(){
        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-1000, duration: 5)
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 3)
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction))

        //Set a timer to destoy the node
        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("destroy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }

    func destroy(){
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

and the next enemy ....

```
class new_fighter : Basic_Fighter  {

    convenience init(){
        self.init()
        health = 5
    }
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: You are not described in the question that is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which exactly question are you asking, but this part is wrong:

```
class new_fighter : Basic_Fighter  {
    convenience init(){
        self.init()
        health = 5
    }
}
```

You can not have convenience initializer declared just as is, without a designated initializer.  Perhaps you should revisit Swift language reference for the part about designated vs. convenience initializers.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID219):

> ... Swift applies the following three rules for delegation calls between initializers:
>
> **Rule 1**
>
> A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the *same* class.
>
> **Rule 3**
>
> A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.

Answer (score 1):

When you subclass SKSPriteNode you must use this designated initializer:

```
init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize)
```

and in your convenience initializer call: `self.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)`